# Configparser in AWS Glue is not reading config file from S3

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-glue, configparser

I am trying to read a config file from S3 bucket via python script run by AWS glue. But the file is not read.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from pyspark import SparkContext
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
import sys
import ConfigParser
from os import path
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
print("My New Job")

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['config_path', 'section_type'])
config_path = args["config_path"]
print("config_path")
print(config_path)

config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
filenameread = config.read(['s3://temp-bucket/config/myconfig.ini','s3://temp-bucket/config/myconfig.config','s3://temp-bucket/config/myconfig.txt'])
print("filenameread")
print(filenameread)
print("sections")
print(config.sections())
```

The log appears as below. The config sections is empty.

```
{
  "timestamp": 1551705899133,
  "message": "Container: container_somenumber on ip-somenumber.ec2.internal_somenumber\nLogType:stdout\nLog Upload Time:Mon Mar 04 13:24:51 +0000 2019\nLogLength:175\nLog Contents:\nMy New Job\nconfig_path\ns3://temp-bucket/config/myconfig.ini\nfilenameread\n[]\nsections\n[]\nEnd of LogType:stdout\n",
   "ingestionTime": 1551705899785
 },
```

Can anybody help on this. Using Python 2.7.15 .

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by defining the `--extra-files` key in the job parameters section.

Due to this, the filepath(s)(comma separated in case of multiple files) mentioned in the value of this key are brought to the run time environment during execution.
Then using configparser, one can easily access the file as a conventional config file.

For more detailed info, refer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-glue-arguments.html